# Best way to remove all the Viewcontroller from navigation controller stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I have some view controller's within the navigation controller stack, hence I want to remove all the view controllers except for parent controller. What is the best way to remove all the view controllers in navigation controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

It should move to the `rootviewcontroller` immediately.

Comment: Sorry, this thing have 10 minutes halt to accept the answer, accepted it is.